# how to fetch data from server through afnetworking in phone sdk

Tags: objective-c, iphone, web-services, afnetworking

I am creating iOS app and trying to fetch data from server through afnetworking code is following

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXXXXX/DisplayDetail.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

But I am getting following error

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x7f9f3943aee0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f9f3954e0b0> { URL: http://run2tour.com/bud_api/DisplayDetail.php } { status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Thu, 29 Jan 2015 07:30:36 GMT";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5";
Server = "Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.34";} 
},
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://run2tour.com/bud_api/DisplayDetail.php, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<5b7b2275 7365725f 6964223a 22313039 222c2275 7365725f 656d6169 6c223a22 616e7572 61674067
```

............

**So please help me how to resolve it.**

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix -In `AFJSONResponseSerializer` class of `AFNetworking` `acceptableContentTypes` field is defined. You have to add `text/html` type there.

Its a JSON response so it should be text/json.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message the content type returned by the server is incorrect. The server does return JSON but the header says its HTML.

Really you should fix the server header.

A bad solution would be to teach AFN to treat HTML MIME type responses as JSON in the response serialisation classes.

Comment: So please tell me what will be code for setting header

Comment: This is a header returned by the server - the app code could be fine. Do you / need to set an accept header?

Answer (score 0):

As @Wain stated, the best approach is changing the header in the backend

for example in you http://XXXXXX/DisplayDetail.php" file you should add

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

*PHP References*
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php